# How to fetch and render object of objects in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have following code and I am trying to display the data from the object of objects. The error that I receive is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined. I understand that the data isn't in the format of 'array of objects', however I still don't know how to properly map it. I would appreciate some help here...

```
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home({ allPosts }) {  
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <section>
        {Object.values(allPosts.bpi).map(({ section, idx }) => (
          <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={idx}>
           {section.description}
          <br />
          {section.code}
          <br />
        </li>
        ))}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  let data = [];
  let error = "";
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
    );
    data = await res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    error = e.toString();
  }

  return {
    props: {
      allPosts: data,
      error,
    },
  };
}
```

Logged data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChWLm.png)

Object looks like this

```
{
"chartName": "Bitcoin",
"bpi": {
      "USD": {
           "code": "USD",
           "symbol": "&#36;",
           "rate": "20,220.5728",
           "description": "United States Dollar",
           "rate_float": 20220.5728
      },
     "GBP": {
           "code": "GBP",
           "symbol": "&pound;",
           "rate": "16,896.1488",
           "description": "British Pound Sterling",
           "rate_float": 16896.1488
      },
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't access the `USD` and `GBP` objects. You are just getting their names. But you can access them by name like this:

```js
<section>
    {Object.values(allPosts.bpi).map((section, idx) => (
        <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={idx}>
           {allPosts.bpi[section].description}
            <br />
            {allPosts.bpi[section].code}
            <br />
        </li>
    ))}
</section>
```

### EDIT

It should be `section.description` instead of `allPosts.bpi[section].description`. Same for the object code.

```js
<section>
    {Object.values(allPosts.bpi).map((section, idx) => (
        <li className={utilStyles.listItem} key={idx}>
           {section.description}
            <br />
            {section.code}
            <br />
        </li>
    ))}
</section>
```

Comment: I still get 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined' error

Comment: Can you try logging data when you fetch it?

Comment: Also, on what line does that error occur?

Comment: I added the pic of logged data and the error occurs on the line  {allPosts.bpi[section].description} or in my case {section.description}

Comment: Did you change `(({ section, idx })` to `((section, idx)`? You don't need to destructure it here.

Comment: @YevheniiStrilets I edited my answer. I think it should work now

Comment: Yes I did, but still getting error. Thought that I need to change something in data fetch section, so I could convert it in array of objects, but not sure if this is a right path...

Comment: @YevheniiStrilets Did you change it to the new code I gave in the answer?

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you! Can you briefly explain why I didn't need to destruct data there?

Comment: @YevheniiStrilets Because when you destructure it, you get the `section` and `idx` properties of that object. But the properties are not there and it returns `undefined`. By the way, you can destructure it so, that you can access only the `code` and the `description` properties: `({ description, code }, idx)` and then access them just like this: `description` or `code`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the map method wrong.
Try this.

```
Object.values(allPosts.bpi).map((section, idx) => ....
```